# Making a css rule override jQuery .css changes

Tags: jquery, css, printing, media-queries

I have two stylesheets: a `media="print"` one and a `media="screen"` one.
I also have some jQuery code that runs on window resize, changing the `margin-left` of a div.

Currently, this div is way off to the right when the user prints.
I want the `margin-left` to always be zero when the user prints.

How could I go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: make the print rule `!important`, maybe?

Comment: adding !important to your stylesheet will override an inline style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give it an `id` and set it to `#your-id { margin-left: whatever !important; }`

Comment: Thanks, the `!important` worked great (it already had an id).
Will accept in 11 mins, when SO lets me :(

Comment: The id was important for specificity. Check out this article: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/ Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Using `!important` in your CSS stylesheet is one option.

Another option might be removing the inline style attribute, and then adding your own using `removeAttr('style')`.